# How to use org.jf.dexlib2 get instructions’ byte code in a dexfile

Tags: java, android, dalvik, dex, smali

I want to get the instruction's byte code,but this code can only get the opcode's byte code.Such as `0x38 01 FB FF` means `if-eqz v1, -0x5`.I can only get `0x38` means `if-eqz` ,but I don't know how to get `0x01 FB FF` which means `v1, -0x5`

```
for (ClassDef classDef: dexfile.getClasses()){
    for (Method method : classDef.getMethods()){
        if (method.getImplementation()==null)
                continue;
        for (Instruction i :method.getImplementation().getInstructions()){
            i.getOpcode().values();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dexlib2 at https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/tree/master/dexlib2/src/main/java/org/jf/dexlib2

Comment: how to dexlib2 try this link... https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/smali/+/ea4ee3e/dexlib2/src/main/java/org/jf/dexlib2/analysis/DumpFields.java

Comment: yes, it can :). The main error I see is that you're not checking if method.getImplementation() is null. It can be null in the case of an abstract method, or methods in an interface. And just a general comment, you shouldn't just say something along the lines of "this doesn't work". You need to describe how and why it doesn't work. What do you expect it to do? What did it do instead?

Comment: Sorry I'm new here,I don't know how to describe my question clearly.Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this,I'm still learning

Comment: Why do you need to know the raw bytes? The more detail you can give, the better of an answer you're likely to get :)

Comment: I expect an api in org.jf.dexlib2.iface.instruction which i can get one instruction's bytecode which i want.I think it can get the smali code by using the annotator,and sure i did that.But I just need the byte code just like I described in the question.I'm thinking of using the offset,but not quite sure

Comment: But why do you want it? What's your goal? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to write a program to analyse the vulnerability in the app.Now I want to model some smali code.If I can get the raw code,I can do more.Or I have to analyse the string translated from the raw code.

Comment: The raw byte values in this case isn't going to be very useful. A lot of the useful/interesting values are going to be context dependent. For example, for a const-string instruction, it references the string by a string id. That string id is likely going to be different in every dex file, even if it's the exact same string. Same for methods, fields, etc.

Comment: So, for example, say you have `const-string v0, "abcd"` in one application, and `const-string v0, "abcd"` in another application. The raw bytes for these instructions will likely be different, because the string tables will be different, and so the string "abcd" will have a different id.

Comment: Oh, it‘s so useful. I never thought about the string. I just thought if I can get the raw code I can get the register number from it rather than use `getRegisterA/B/C/D()`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use baksmali's -D option to print an annotated hex dump of a dex file. This will produce a 2-column hex dump, with the left column containing the raw byte values, and the right column containing annotations about what those bytes are, as per the dex specification.

For example:

```
> baksmali -N -D penroser.dump penroser.apk
> less penroser.dump

... (lots of other stuff :))

                           |[26] code_item: Lafzkl/development/mColorPicker/views/ColorPickerView;->pointToHue(F)F
0075f4: 0600               |  registers_size = 6
0075f6: 0200               |  ins_size = 2
0075f8: 0100               |  outs_size = 1
0075fa: 0000               |  tries_size = 0
0075fc: 8690 0100          |  debug_info_off = 0x19086
007600: 2100 0000          |  insns_size = 0x21
                           |  instructions:
007604: 1503 b443          |    const/high16 v3, 1135869952 # 360.000000
007608: 5441 1e00          |    iget-object v1, v4, Lafzkl/development/mColorPicker/views/ColorPickerView;->mHueRect:Landroid/graphics/RectF;
00760c: 6e10 a700 0100     |    invoke-virtual {v1}, Landroid/graphics/RectF;->height()F
007612: 0a00               |    move-result v0
007614: 5212 3b00          |    iget v2, v1, Landroid/graphics/RectF;->top:F
007618: 2e02 0502          |    cmpg-float v2, v5, v2
00761c: 3b02 0900          |    if-gez v2, +0x9
007620: 1205               |    const/4 v5, 0
007622: a802 0503          |    mul-float v2, v5, v3
007626: c902               |    div-float/2addr v2, v0
007628: a702 0302          |    sub-float v2, v3, v2
00762c: 0f02               |    return v2
00762e: 5212 3800          |    iget v2, v1, Landroid/graphics/RectF;->bottom:F
007632: 2d02 0502          |    cmpl-float v2, v5, v2
007636: 3d02 0400          |    if-lez v2, +0x4
00763a: 0105               |    move v5, v0
00763c: 28f3               |    goto -0xd
00763e: 5212 3b00          |    iget v2, v1, Landroid/graphics/RectF;->top:F
007642: c725               |    sub-float/2addr v5, v2
007644: 28ef               |    goto -0x11
007646: 0000               |
```

Comment: Thanks for all.But I'm not asking this.I want to get the raw code in a program which i'm writing to analyse the vulnerabilities in an android app.I  need an api or some code to get the raw code when i iterate a method‘s instructions like the code in the question.In order words ,I want to do something to i in the question code to get i's raw code.